# AWS S3 object with data sensitive object names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We name the S3 object name with the birthday of the employees. It is stupid. We want to avoid creating object name with sensitive data. Is it safe to store the sensitive data using S3 user-defined metadata or Add an S3 bucket policy that denies the action S3:Getobject. Which will work?

Comment: Depending on your industry, personally identifiable information, such as a birthday, could be regulated. Redesign your systems and policies so that this information is always protected from both outside the company but also from employees who should not have access to this data.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned; its not a good idea to create object name with sensitive data; but its ok... Not too bad also.. I will suggest to remove listAllObjects() permissions in the S3 policy. Policy should only allow getObject() which means anyone can get the object ONLY when they know object name; i.e. when calling api already knows DOB of the user.

With listAllObjects() permissions; caller can list all the objects in the bucket and get DOB of users.

Answer (score 0):

Object keys and user metadata should not be used for sensitive data.  The reasoning behind object keys is readily apparent, but metadata may be less obvious;

- metadata is returned in the HTTP headers every time an object is fetched.  This can't be disabled, but it can be worked around with CloudFront and Lambda@Edge response triggers, which can be used to redact the metadata when the object is downloaded through CloudFront; however,
- metadata is not stored encrypted in S3, even if the object itself is encrypted.

Object tags are also not appropriate for sensitive data, because they are also not stored encrypted.  Object tags are useful for flagging objects that contain sensitive data, because tags can be used in policies to control access permissions on the object, but this is only relevant when the object itself contains the sensitive data.

In the case where "sensitive" means "proprietary" rather than "personal," tags can be an acceptable place for data... this might be data that is considered sensitive from a business perspective but that does not need to be stored encrypted, such as the identification of a specific software version that created the object.  (I use this strategy so that if a version of code is determined later to have a bug, I can identify which objects might have been impacted because they were generated by that version).  You might want to keep this information proprietary but it would not be "sensitive" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If your s3 bucket is used to store private data and your allowing public access to the bucket this is always a bad idea - it's basically security by obscurity.

Instead of changing your existing s3 structure you could lock down the bucket to just your app then you serve the data via cloudfront signed urls?

Basically in your code where you currently inject the s3 url You can instead call the aws api to create a signed url from the s3 url and a policy and send this new url to the end user. This would mask the s3 url, and you can enforce other restrictions like how long the link is valid, enforce requiring a specific header or limit access to a specific ip etc. You also get cdn edge caching and reduced costs as side benefits.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html